# Vb.Net convert StrDup to C#.net

Tags: c#, vb.net, strdup

I have this line of code:

```
strKey &= Strings.StrDup(intKeySize - intLength, chrKeyFill)
```

What is the equivalent of this code in C#? I can't seem to find it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
strKey += new String(chrKeyFill, intKeySize - intLength);
```

or

```
strKey = strKey.PadRight(intKeySize, chrKeyFill)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
strKey += strKey.PadRight(strKey.Length + (intKeySize - intLength), chrKeyFill)
```

Answer (score 0):

Personally I think the String constructor approach is clumsy and less readable than the VB.Net Strings library.

```
 using Microsoft.VisualBasic;
 ...
 Strings.StrDup(2, '\t');
```